# RHEL 4 reboot causes Tomcat process to not be started by non-root account

Tags: linux, reboot, users, tomcat, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a startup script placed in /etc/init.d wherein I make the following call:

```
nohup sudo -u myuser $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh 2>&1
```

This causes Tomcat to be run as myuser, which is expected.  However after issuing the reboot command the system starts up and root is now the owner of this process.  How can I force the process to be started off as myuser on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you do not have multiple scripts starting the process, and the one that is called first is configured to run as root? The script should have the same effect when started as root at startup as during operation.

What are the operating system specifics?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you would like to know about the system?

Comment: I am sorry, I missed RHEL in the topic.